# Storing Loop output value

Tags: loops, lisp, repeat, autolisp

Hi i am developing a program in Autolisp. It consists of 2 routine files. 1st one is main routine and 2nd  is sub routine. After loading the program 1st the sub routine file will start run. In the sub routine i have a loop coding. I used repeat loop. The loop will run for n times, and it will generate outputs for n times. (i.e. weight of a product WT1, WT2, WT3,etc...). After this the main routine will start run. There i want all the above weights for further calculation.  (i.e. weight of a product WT1, WT2, WT3,etc...). how do i store the weight and use it in main routine file?. as of now i am getting the last weight only. i want wt1, wt2, wt3.

Thanks in advance.

Storing LOOP output and calling it in another routine.

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far, so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1):

As the last expression in function where the loop runs, use variable where You collect values inside the loop. It amy looks like this

```
(defun calculateValues ( / )
   (setq n 5)
   (setq i 0)
   (repeat n
      (setq result (append result (list i)))
      (setq i (1+ i))
   )
   result 
)
```

It's hard to say when we don't see the code, but I hope it will help.

Comment: instead of repeatedly calling `append`, which leads to quadratic behavior, consider using `cons` in the loop, as `(setq results (cons i results))`. then use `(reverse results)` as the last value.